# How to avoid to get special characters on QInputDialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to prevent the text box from the user to avoid typing the special characters. I have tried with `keyPressEvent` but it's called after clicking the OK button.

Code:

```
text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(
    self, "Create category", "Enter category name:", QLineEdit.Normal, ""
)
if okPressed and text != "":
    print(text)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    print("keyPressEvent")
    print(event)
```

How can I avoid some specific characters in the QInputDialog?

Comment: You can do the same as the duplicated post by using a QValidator or just installing an event filter on the QLineEdit.

Comment: Please read the question, it's not related to Completer. It's the question to avoid special characters in the text box...! @musicamante

Comment: Yes, I read the question. And have you understood my comment?